# Reading upper case values from a list in another work book before copying and pasting values

Tags: excel, vba, module

I have workbook with a list. I have written this code whereby the user can download the latest file to update the population figures. The function below allows user to open the file, and the code will cross reference the list before pasting the value in the column specified.

***To try and explain it better:
Column A has a list of cities/towns etc, and Column B is empty.
The new workbook that is selected has the list of cities and population numbers against it. The function below checks that the list in the new workbook matches the one in the activeworkbook before pasting the value into the empty cell. However I noticed sometimes if there is upper case, it doesn't pick it up.***

One issue I have noticed is that if the list has an upper case in the second word for example it does not get picked up. I know I need to use a form of logical comparison but I am unsure how to apply it in the below code. *This may be something very simple to others but I am pretty fresh to VBA in Excel.*

> UCase(....)=UCase(...)

```
Sub eng_qof()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim my_Filename As Variant
Dim my_File As Workbook
Dim xcol, ycol, frow As Integer
Dim I As Integer
Dim pop As Range

    my_Filename = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel Files, *xl*;*.xm*")

    If my_Filename <> False Then
    Set my_File = Application.Workbooks.Open(my_Filename)
    
    
    
    xcol = Workbooks("City list.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B15:B146").Count
    
    For I = 15 To 15 + xcol
        answer1 = Workbooks("City list.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & I).Value
    Set pop = myFile.Sheets("list").Range("C" & I).Value
    If pop Is Nothing Then
       Workbooks("City list.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D" & I).Value = ""
    Else
        frow = Workbooks("City list.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B12:B146").Find(what:=answer1)
        my_File.Sheets("list").Range("L" & I).Value = Workbooks("City list.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D" & I).Value
    
    'my_File.Sheets("list").Range("L15:L149").Copy
    'Workbooks("City list.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D12").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    
    'my_File.Close False
    End If
Next I
    End If
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: `Set pop = myFile.Sheets("list").Range("C" & I).Value` - following this, `pop` will never be `Nothing` - it will always refer to a Range object (for valid values of `I`).  Did you intend to check for cell *content*?  You can do that like `If Len(pop.Value) > 0 Then`

Comment: I have added some more information on the original post to try an explain what I am trying to do. As far as I am aware it doesnt open my_Filename twice :/

Comment: Is `City list.xlsm` where the code is running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vlookup is not case-sensitive, so you can try that.

Untested:

```vb
Sub eng_qof()
    Dim my_Filename As Variant, ws As Worksheet
    Dim my_File As Workbook, c As Range, v, res
    
    my_Filename = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel Files, *xl*;*.xm*")
    If my_Filename = False Then Exit Sub 'exit if no file selected
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set my_File = Application.Workbooks.Open(my_Filename)
    
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") 'assumes code is running in "City list.xlsm"
    'loop cells in ColB
    For Each c In ws.Range("B15:B146").Cells
        v = c.Value 'value to look up
        If Len(v) > 0 Then
            'vlookup is not case-sensitive: returns value from Col L or error value if no match
            res = Application.VLookup(v, my_File.Sheets("list").Range("B:L"), 11, False)
            If Not IsError(res) Then
                'match was made
                c.EntireRow.Columns("D").Value = res
            Else
                ' ? What to do if no match ?
            End If
        End If
    Next c
    my_File.Close False
End Sub
```